# Deploying UWP App to the App Store With .Net Native

Tags: win-universal-app

does Deploying a UWP application to the app store require application to be compiled with .NET Native? or it is optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You submit to the Store .appxupload package, which only contains IL binaries. Store will compile your package itself using cloud-hosted compiler and same version of .Net Native toolchain as you did. As far as I know, you can't opt out. [Some more info.](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/)

Comment: it is so bad, why Microsoft does this? because  the result is different is some codes, why other developers doesn't have any problem with this? the compilation is slow and you should change some of your code

Comment: Could you describe your problem with .Net Native in details?

Comment: for example in EF7  I want to use join query, but I can't